# Java DecimalFormat rounding down

Tags: java, decimalformat

I am using DecimalFormatter to read in formatted decimal string values and convert them to float. However, when I run:

```
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("####,####.00");
    String floatStr = "177,687.71";
    float val1 = formatter.parse(floatStr).floatValue();
    System.out.println(val1);
```

...I get 177678.7 instead of 177678.71. Why is this? How do I avoid rounding the hundredths place?

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't use `float` or `double` to store precise decimal values.  That looks like an amount of money - so may I suggest the `BigDecimal` type instead?  And to answer your question, a `float` is generally only accurate to around 7 significant figures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to need more precision than a float to represent that number.

Taking the formatter out of the picture:

```
Float.parseFloat("177687.71");
177687.7 // Ouch

Double.parseDouble("177687.71");
177687.71 // Ok
```

It seems that you'll need to use a double instead.

If this is for representing money though as @Dawood is suggesting , then yes, do not use floating types to represent money, since they are estimations and will accumulate errors over time. A format like BigDecimal would be more appropriate, or even just storing an integer representing cents. Money is not something that you want to subject to rounding errors.